# Show that the set is a subspace of the vector space of all real-valued functions on the given domain

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

.., under the operations of function addition and scalar multiplication.

The set of all continuous real-valued functions f defined on the interval [0,1] such that $\int_0^1f(x)\mathrm dx =0$

No idea on how to begin to proving subspaces for integrals.

Answer (score 1):

This just means that$$\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx=0\text{ and }\int_0^1g(x)\,\mathrm dx=0\implies\int_0^1f(x)+g(x)\,\mathrm dx=0$$and that, if $\lambda\in\mathbb R$,$$\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx=0\implies\int_0^1\lambda f(x)\,\mathrm dx=0.$$

Comment: In this case, lambda is any real number?

Comment: @ChocolateAndMath Yes.

Comment: Gotcha. So, we're basically showing that the set is closed under addition and scalar multiplication? And it is already given that it has {0}. Therefore, the set is a subspace?

Comment: @ChocolateAndMath I wouldn't say that it is given that it has $0$; I'd say that it is trivial. And, yes, that's why it is a subspace.

Comment: Why is it trivial? Don't we need that as one of the conditions to prove that it is a subspace? If not, then in what cases is that condition considered trivial?

Comment: @ChocolateAndMath What I wrote was that the assertion that $0$ belongs to your space is trivial. In other words, it is trivial that $\int_0^10\,\mathrm dx=0$. Yes, it is one of conditions, although it can be replaced by the weeker condition that says that the set is not empty (but the usual way of proving that it is not empty consists in proving that $0$ belongs to it).

Comment: Got it. So in cases where it says =0, it is implying that 0 belongs to the space. For example, f defined on the interval [0, 1] s. t., f(1/2)=0?

Comment: @ChocolateAndMath No. My $0$ is the null function, not the number $0$.